# Keras infinite loop

Tags: tf.keras

The code reads my images from colab folders. then it splits the codes as training set and validation set using generator. I used an existing premodel Dense201 to train it. However I am not sure why, for the  the generator remains caught in an infinite loop and the loop that generates the validation data never executes.  Does anyone know how to circumvent this ?

[image]

```
    import tensorflow as tf



    IMAGE_SIZE = 224
     BATCH_SIZE = 64

datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255, 
    validation_split=0.2)

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    base_dir,
    target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, 
    subset='training')

val_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    base_dir,
    target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, 
    subset='validation')

base_model = tf.keras.applications.DenseNet201(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                              include_top=False, 
                                              weights='imagenet')
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  base_model,
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax')
])
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), 
              loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_generator, 
                    epochs=2, 
                    steps_per_epoch=100,
                    validation_data=val_generator)
```

Comment: adding on, it was all ok 2 weeks ago when i was running in colab

Comment: I had the same problem. Downgrading Tensorflow to version 2.1.0 will fix the problem once. (`pip install tensorflow==2.1.0`)

Answer (score 0):

In the line:

```
history = model.fit(train_generator, 
                epochs=2, 
                steps_per_epoch=100,
                validation_data=val_generator)
```

change `steps_per_epoch=100` to `steps_per_epoch=(len(train_generator)//BATCH_SIZE)`

Comment: It still go on infinite loops, it wasnt like this earlier

epochs = 2
history = model.fit(train_generator, 
                    epochs=epochs, 
                    steps_per_epoch=(train_generator.n//BATCH_SIZE),
                    validation_data=val_generator)

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked!

```
!pip uninstall tensorflow

!pip install tensorflow==2.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue arises because your validation generator is stuck in an infinite loop unable to exit. While data generator exits due to **steps_per_epoch=100** argument you provided you haven't specified how many time the generator must be called until your validation loss is calculated. There's a similar argument that fixes this issue called **validation_steps**

```
history = model.fit(train_generator, 
                epochs=2, 
                steps_per_epoch=100,
                validation_data=val_generator
                validation_steps=50)
```

this way your validation loss will be calculated based on the data your validation generator returns for 50 calls, and it won't get stuck in an infinite loop